# Execute when dark mode is toogled

Tags: bash, gnome

I want to create a simple bash file and I want it to run whenever I turn on or off the darkmode.

Where and how should I place the file??

Comment: what's a `dark mode`? ... how do you enable it?

Comment: maybe you can think this instead ... `I want to create a simple bash file and I want it to turn on or off the darkmode`

Comment: Yeah, I found that easier, thanks